# How do I stop the Shakturi?

Tags: distant-worlds-shakturi

I've played trough the original distant worlds several times, but the return of the Shakturi expansion pack is giving me some difficulty.

Two years ago the Shakturi began their war on the on the good races of the galaxy. At the start of the war I had several colonies near their borders, my military was the most powerful in the galaxy.

[image: Start of the war]
In the above screenshot my empire is represented in Dark blue. The light blue to my south west are the Great Ackdurian kingdom, who are my allies. The Shakturi territory is the Purple area in the south east.

---

Two years into the war things have turned a bit desperate. Shakturi world destroyers are destroying planets with impunity. My own fleets have proven to slow to catch those of the Shakturi, when combat does take place the Shakturi usually outnumber and outgun me.

The Great Ackdurian kingdom has been wiped out, and my colonies in Kiadia, Osis, Lanos and Vun-Alea have been destroyed. 
[image: two years into the war]

---

The core planets of the human empire are now threatened directly by the Shakturi. My military has been gutted, and I still have not found a way to deal with world destroyers popping into a system and immediately destroying a planet.

Is my situation hopeless? Is there anything I can do to defeat the Shakturi or should I have handled things differently at the start of the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gotten yourself several Planet Destroyers that you use to destroy their planets when they're not there.
Never take on their fleets 1 on 1. Your fleets will only be annihilated.
You're probably dead now. But for next war, strike where they are not. And fall back when they come. Also, do the quests for the Ancient Guardians. It's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a few solid tactics to dealing with the shakturi

Priority 1: Incite a revolution so they lose their redicilous way of darkness bonuses

Priority 2: ensure that you have maxed out research on warp disruption technology and you have monitoring stations around your empire so that you can see them coming in pleanty of time.

If you stations are equipped with high tech warp jammers then the shakturi will warp in evenly spread around the circumference of the dead zone around your station thus their firepower will be dramatically thinned out. If you have a fleet bunched up and lying in wait on the outside edge then you can cut through their thinly spread fleet like wheat to a scythe.

The by far easiest way of defeating is to hit them with everything you have as soon as they arrive in the galaxy, while they are still the refugees. At that point you can completely exterminate them with orbital bombardment... however this really feels like cheating.

I NEVER join the freedom alliance when asked, because that way I can bleed the shakturi for vast amounts of money and the ancient guardians for vast amounts of tech by agreeing to trade sanction their enemies. During this time of fake neutrality you can manipulate the entire galaxy to war dec the shakturi thus driving up their war weariness (which will never decrease as the ancient guardians will maintain a state of perpetual war with them). The more wars teh shakturi have ongoing the less likely they are to want yet another war going on thus adding to their war weariness multiplier.

Maintaining a fake neutrality allowed me to hugely benefit from the shakturi turning up and dig in BIG time. You can give all the empuires that are at war with the shakturi millitary refueling rights but not give them to the shakturi. If your playing in a huge universe then refueling rights are a big thing. I basically waged a gourilla war against the shakturi by cutting off their access to fuel wherever I could, thus slowing down their expansion while that war weariness continues to rise and rise.